# How to use ArrayList.addAll()

Tags: arraylist

Firstly, I define two class:

```
Class Job{

  int id;
  double prio;

  }

 Class Request{

  int r_id;
  ArrayList<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();

  }
```

And there will be a function like this:

```
Partition(ArrayList<Request> request){

         ArrayList <Job> res = new ArrayList<Job>();
         for(int i=0; i<request.size(); i++){
                   res.addAll(request.get(i).jobs);
            }
   }
```

I thought that each element in the new ArrayList "res" in function "Partition" should maintain the values of "prio" of each element in the "request.get(i).jobs". However, we I visit them, all the "prio" value become "0.0" . How can I maintain the properties' value of the input variable when using .addAll() method? Thank you!!!!

Comment: `double prio;` is the same as `double prio = 0.0;`. You never initialize the value to anything else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're never initialising the value of pro. When you create an instance of Job, pro is initialised to 0.0 by default.
Create a setter method in Job class to set the value if you need to set it after creating an instance of job,

```
Class Job {

    int id;
    double prio;

    public void setPro(double d) {
        this.pro = d;
    }

    public void setId(int i) {
        this.id = i;
    }

    public void toString() {
        System.out.println("pro = " + pro + ", " + " ID is " + id);
    }
}
```

Then you can create an instance and set the value like,

```
Job j = new Job();
j.setPro(1.5);
j.setId(44);
j.toString(); /* this prints "pro = 1.5, ID is 44" */
```

otherwise create a constructor for the Job class and set the value of pro within the constructor, so the value is set when you create an instance of Job.

```
Class Job {

    int id;
    double prio;

    Job (int id, double pro) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pro = pro;
    }

    public void toString() {
        System.out.println("pro = " + pro + ", " + " ID is " + id);
    }
}
```

Then you can create an instance with the values like,

```
Job j = new Job(44, 1.5);
j.toString(); /* this prints "pro = 1.5, ID is 44" */
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have installed the value of "pro"， just omitting in this question. If you visit like:  "request.get(0).jobs.get(0).prio", the pro has value. But if you visit directly like "res.get(0).prio", it returns "0.0"

Comment: It's bit hard to tell what's happening without having a look at the full code. Can you post more of your code?